# Почему кракозябры в Теме письма в «Opera Mail»?

Tags: golang, кодировка, email

Мылю письмо:

```
var msg = []byte("To: " + myMail + "\r\n" +
  "Subject: " + "Тема письма" + "\r\n" +
  "Это содержимое письма.")
var err = smtp.SendMail(HostPortSMTP, auth, MailFrom, []string{myMail}, msg)
```

Как я понимаю, оно уходит в кодировке UTF-8... И на веб-странице - на почтовом сервере - все нормально выглядит, но в почтовом клиенте "Opera Mail" в Теме [вместо кириллицы] кракозябры.
Как решить? Как это вообще делается? Может как-то запрашивается требуемая для клиента кодировка?
Ведь приходящие письма в этом клиенте отображаются нормально.

Comment: Потому что в заголовках письма нельзя указывать неанглийские буквы, нужно закодировать их специальным образом (но я не знаю как сделать это в golang)

Comment: Понятно.
Есть вот такой способ специально кодировать:
func DecodeWindows1251(ba []uint8) []uint8 {
    var dec = charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder()
    var out, _ = dec.Bytes(ba)
    return out
}
Но это не помогает - кракозябры меняются на другие. Либо кодировку надо другую указывать, но неясно как.

Comment: Наверное Opera Mail позволяет скачать сообщение как файл (raw message). Скачайте и посмотрите, какие байты стоят у вас в поле Subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас [RFC 6532](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6532) предписывает почтовым агентам поддерживать UTF-8. Но в времена оны, когда Юникод ещё бегал в коротких штанишках (1992-й год), в [RFC 1342](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1342) была предложена схема кодирования `encoded words`, которую, по идее, до сих пор все поддерживают.

Идея была в том, чтобы не-ASCII символы кодировать отдельно от ASCII символов. Я не буду погружаться в детали, расскажу чисто конкретно на примере `utf-8`.

Строка `Тема письма` кодируется так: `=?utf-8?B?0KLQtdC80LAg0L/QuNGB0YzQvNCwCg==?=`

Закодированная строка начинается с префикса `=?`, затем идёт название кодировки, следом после разделителя `?` буква `B` означает, что байтовая строка закодирована `base64`. Между `?` и `?=` располагаются байты строки `Тема письма`, сначала закодированные в `utf-8`, а потом в `base64`.

Протестируйте ваш почтовый агент, подсунув ему в тему письма строку

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?0KLQtdC80LAg0L/QuNGB0YzQvNCwCg==?=
```

Comment: Тест успешен. Но зачем кодировать в UTF-8, разве Go по умолчанию не выдает строки в UTF-8? И как кодировать в base64 (или сначала в utf-8, а потом в base64)?

Comment: Заработало, спасибо! :)